# Removing char in Jquery/Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/305/) the 3rd column seems not adding right because the last value has a comma(,) in value. How can it be right without removing the comma(,) directly? I know adding **.replace(/,/g,'')** can help but I don't know where should be put that.

this is the code:

```
$('.add').click(function (e) {
    $('#paytable tr:first td').each(function () {
        var $td = $(this);

        var colTotal = 0;
        $('#paytable tr:not(:first,.totalColumn)').each(function () {
            colTotal += parseInt($(this).children().eq($td.index()).html(), 10);
        });

        $('#paytable tr.totalColumn').children().eq($td.index()).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/DuuWn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/306/

Here is the code:

```
 $('.add').click(function(e) {
 $('#paytable tr:first td').each(function(){
 var $td = $(this);

  var colTotal = 0;
  $('#paytable tr:not(:first,.totalColumn)').each(function(){
    colTotal  += parseInt($(this).children().eq($td.index()).html().replace(/,/g, ""),10);
    });

    $('#paytable tr.totalColumn').children().eq($td.index()).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.add').click(function (e) {
    $('#paytable tr:first td').each(function (idx) {
        var $td = $(this);

        var colTotal = 0;
        $('#paytable td.rowDataSd:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ')').each(function () {
            colTotal += parseInt($(this).html().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
        });

        $('#paytable tr.totalColumn').children().eq(idx).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NY3J/)